# Why read about Rashb"i's death at a memorial ceremony?

Tags: minhag, mourning-aveilus, zohar, rabbi-shimon-bar-yochai

Why do many people read the passage (known as [אדרא זוטא](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%96%D7%95%D7%98%D7%90)) from *Zohar* about the death of Rabbi Shim'on ben Yochai at memorial ceremonies?

A description of it can be found [here](http://daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2054).

Comment: Can you describe the passage? Is there something that most people would find meaningful about life or death? For instance, the passages in the Talmud regarding Rabbi Yehuda HaNassi's death, for instance, are important for understanding end-of-life care issues, but not particularly meaningful to be read at a memorial.

Comment: @Shalom - I am searching for the text or a citation, but meanwhile I assume it is whatever they are selling here: http://www.rashbbi.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=173&Itemid=162&lang=he

Comment: The text is here: http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%96%D7%95%D7%98%D7%90 And a description of it here: http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=2054